What is the difference between thrust and lift?
I calculated the thrust and power of the helicopter to hover above the surface, but I'm not sure if I calculated correctly. I've already asked a similar question, but I've moved on, and there are more questions.
Is it possible to use the formula of the thrust equation for a helicopter on Venus?
Initial data:
$
W = 300\text{ kg},  
\rho = 65~\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}, 
C_\text{T} = 0.028,
N_\text{rotors} = 1.
$
Suppose that:
$
\omega = 300\text{ rpm} = 31.415\text{ rad/s}; R = 1\text{ m}.
$
Now let's calculate remembering that Helicopter has 1 rotor
$T =1 \cdot \frac12 \cdot65(31.415\cdot1)^2 \pi 1^2 \cdot 0.028 = 2925\text{ N}$
I calculated the power according to this formula for hovering the helicopter outside the "ground effect".
I used instead of $L$, thrust $T = 2925\text{ N}$. Is this correct, or should I use $L=m \cdot g$? I did it with a thrust of $T, P = 9789\text{ N}$. I can't figure out if that's a lot or a little. What does $L=m \cdot g$ mean then, I have $L = 300 \cdot 8.87 = 2661 \text{ N}$. What is the difference between $T = 2925 \text{ N}$ and $L = 2661 \text{ N}$? And the following question arises: from what height does the "ground effect" cease to act and how to calculate it when it acts?

A note: in your linked question you computed T = 2820 N but here you list it as 2925.

@randomhead Thanks, I fixed the bug.

In the aerospace world, the word "thrust" is used when describing the lifting/pushing force generated by a rotor, a propeller or a rocket engine. The term "lift" is used when dealing with wings/fuselages/empennages/control surfaces.
Note that, being the blades of a rotor/propeller also termed "rotating wings", the lifting force that each of them generates is also called "lift"; anyway their sum (normally acting at the center of the rotor/propeller) is called "thrust".
In your specific case, the maximum thrust $T$ generated by the rotor must be bigger than the weight $mg$ of your helicopter $T\geq mg$ so that your rotor is able to make the helicopter not only hover but also climb.

Hello. If it's not too much trouble, could you answer my previous question here? I sent you the density, viscosity and speed of sound in the atmosphere of Venus, as you asked. Unfortunately, my previous question was deleted (https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/106981/87892).

$mg$ is how much thrust the helicopter needs to hover at zero airspeed. Any less thrust and it will accelerate downwards and any more thrust and it will accelerate upwards.
The other formula you used is to calculate the thrust that the rotor can provide given a certain rpm and other rotor properties. Since that number is bigger than $mg$, the helicopter would accelerate upwards if a rotor with those properties were spun at 300 rpm.
